# How to use custom meta box from download monitor in download button?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make custom buttons for [download monitor wp plugin](https://www.download-monitor.com/kb). i made a php file and define it for plugin and everything is fine. I can show file size, download link, title and etc using download monitor functions. but I want some custom details. for that I made a custom meta using custom fields in add download called `download_language` now I want to show this value in my button. so I use this:

```
<?php 
echo (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'download_language', true ));
?>
```

but it doesn't show me anything.

Edit: I got that is because post id. it get my custom post id not my download id. when I use my download id everything is fine:

```
<?php echo (get_post_meta( '21', 'download_language', true )); ?>
```

Comment: So, did you solve this? If your "Edit" is the solution, please post it as an answer.